# Why do I need "\n" in c, when using the sleep function?

Tags: c, printf, sleep, unistd.h

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(){
    printf("I sleep\n");
    sleep(3);
    printf("\033[H\033[J");
    return 0;
}
```

if I don't write "\n" in the printf-function, "I sleep" wil not be displayed, until sleep(3) is done.

Can someone explain? Thanks!

Comment: This is because `stdout` is (generally) line buffered. Try `fprintf`ing to `stderr` without `'\n'` instead and it should probably work fine.

Comment: `printf("I sleep"); fflush(stdout);` may be an option

Comment: Surely we must have some good duplicate for this? I can't find one though.

Comment: @AdrianMole Looks good.

Answer (score 1):

The standard output stream, when not outputting to a file or device, is line-buffered by default on most UNIX-like systems.

That mean that text sent there typically won't actually be printed until a newline character is encountered.

Comment: Thanks mate, now I understand!

Comment: "line-buffered by default. " --> Hmmm, I do not see any C spec that says that. Instead common practice.